# See anchor points on objects even when they're not selected - Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, path, anchor-point

Title says it all. I wan't to be able to see anchor points on "object 1" when working with "object 2" so I can align better.

[image]

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: What do you mean by object 1 and object 2?

Comment: @Rishab basically, if I am working on one object like the picture show (object 1) I want to be able to then start working with another object such as a shape or line (object 2) but I still want the anchor points to show on "object 1" when I deselect it.

Comment: i don't think there is any method or properties exist which can do that

Comment: @Rishab well there should! :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I haven't found a way to do this, I often find myself wanting the same thing.

What I do in cases like this is drag out two `Guides` (one horizontal and one vertical) and snap them to the point I want to keep track of before deselecting the object:
[image: guides to show location of anchor point]

This way you can see where the anchor point is, and even have Illustrator snap objects to the intersection of the two guides - as if it was a point.

Comment: Ah interesting work around. Thanks for that, I will try this in the future and see how I get on. As I don't think there is a way to do what I want, I will vote you as correct as it is the best option I have.